# node js getting the image from the mysql and show in html page

Tags: mysql, node.js

this is my html code for getting an image from the mysql database table

```
<html ng-app="imgApp">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/imgController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="imgController">
<img data-ng-repeat="data:image/png;base64,{{base64String}}">
<p>{{variable}}</p>
<button ng-click="getImageFunc()">Get data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

my backend server.js code
 is given below i cant get my image in html page .
kindly check this code and correct  the errors.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var mysql = require('mysql')

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'vinoth',
  database: 'test'
})

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
})


app.get('/getimage',function(request,response){
    connection.query ('select img from pic ',function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
        response.send(result);
    });
})

app.listen(4000);
console.log("sever listening at port 4000");
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: s i tryed it loads only the binary digit values not the image the image is not displayed.

Comment: How are you sending the image from back end can you post your code?

Comment: i have edited the code check that

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `content-type: image/jpeg` or `image/gif` depends on type

```
app.get('/getimage', function(request, response) {
    connection.query('select img from pic ', function(err, result) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        });
        response.send(result); // Send the image to the browser.
    });
});
```

Comment: iam not getting any response from the browser it comes blank

Comment: what is your image type it's `jpeg`?

Comment: use send instead of end I am not sure is the issue

Comment: s i have this error in console                    angular.js:117 Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=data%3Aimage%2Fjpg%3Bbase64%2C%7B%7Bbase64String%7D%7D

Comment: You should check your angular part, also check the error in back-end code